# A problem in the derivation of distributed multiple model filtering

Tags: probability, distributions, conditional-probability, markov-process

I have some problems with the derivation of multi-model filtering in a paper. The involved statements in this paper are as follows.

[image]

[image]

My question is how did the above formula get from left to right?

Also, does the "first two moments of $x_k$" in paragraph 1 refer to the first two time steps? why specifically mentioned here?

The paper's link: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5953482

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you link to the relevant paper?

Comment: thank you, I attached the paper's link as above